# Why do I need to add sleep for rspec to pass with selenium 2.48.0?

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec

Recently we upgraded our selenium web driver from 2.47.1 to 2.48.0.

With this upgrade I need to add `sleep` for a few seconds in rspec to pass. Spec was working properly without `sleep` with the older version.

```
sleep(inspection_time=5) // why do I need this?
my_form_page.save_button.click
// some assertion here
```

**Edit**

I tried using implicit wait instead of sleep.But it's not working. Is there any specific reason behind it?

```
Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, rspec selenium tests are known to be "flakey". Sometimes rspec tries to search for an element before it appears on page due to many reasons (ie: element appears upon ajax response).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tip that may help you solve this, **if you will wrap your [capybara finders](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders) inside of a [within block](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders), your tests will wait until it finds that within selector FIRST before trying to run the code inside of it.**

This more-often-than-not will help solve a test running too fast on a page that takes a while to load and your button or selector or whatever isn't actually on the page yet (which is why it fails).

So take a look at these 2 examples and try the within method...

```
# spec/features/home_page_spec.rb
require "spec_helper"

describe "the home page", type: :feature do
  context "form" do

    # THIS MIGHT FAIL!!!!
    it "submits the form", js: true, driver: :selenium do
      visit "/"
      find("#submit_button").click
    end

    # THIS PROBABLY WILL PASS!!! 
    it "submits the form", js: true, driver: :selenium do
      visit "/"
      within "form" do
        find("#submit_button").click
      end
    end
  end
end
```